# is __init__.py essentially required for a package to be imported

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

```
from distutils import tests
```

this seems to not be throwing any errors even though there is no __init__.py in distutils/tests.

my understanding uto this point was that __init__.py is essentially required for a package or subpackage to be imported

Comment: How did you determine that it doesn't have an ``__init__.py``? My version certainly has one.

Comment: Note: ``__init__`` is only required in python2.

Comment: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/distutils/tests/__init__.py

Comment: For Python 3.3+ read: [PEP 420 -- Implicit Namespace Packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This apparently changed in Python 3.2.  In the [setuptools documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#developer-s-guide)
we find:

```
Anyway, find_packages() walks the target directory, filtering by inclusion         patterns, and finds Python packages (any directory). On Python 3.2 and earlier, packages are only recognized if they include an __init__.py file. Finally, exclusion patterns are applied to
```

However, in the [Python 3.6 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) we find a claim that **init**.py is still required.

My understanding is that the current behavior accepts any directory on sys.path with .py files in it.  However, I am having a hard time digging up something official for that.